# SwiftUI: Present Sf Symbol in alert not showing

Tags: swiftui, uialertview, xcode14, sf-symbols

I'm trying to implement a SwiftUI alert with the following message:

[image]

The message contains a SF Symbol.

Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showsAlert = false
    var body: some View {
        Text("Well done \(Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle"))")
            .padding(10)
        Button(action: {
            self.showsAlert.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show Alert")
        }
        .alert(isPresented: self.$showsAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Title"),
                  message: Text("Well done \(Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle"))"))
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is the alert is not showing the SF Symbol.

Any of you know why this is not working or if there is a way around this to show the SF Symbol?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why not use a Label instead of a Text component? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/label

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Can you post a sample?

Comment: Look at the link I added to my comment

Comment: @JoakimDanielson If I try use the Label in the alert I'm getting this message `Cannot convert value of type 'Label<Text, Image>' to expected argument type 'Text?'`

Comment: Ah, I see now you have two places with the string “Well done”. I only saw the first one.

Comment: Why don't you use a custom view and present it modally instead?

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: use emoji, e.g. `Text("Well done ✔")`